# How to store autolayout anchors mapped onto UIView classes

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm currently working on a very interactive UI. Views need to be moved based on userInput. I've got about six views all with child UI elements stored as separate classes. In my main viewController I want to handle the resetting of these view's constraints. In order to do so I need to store the NSLayout constraints somewhere. Piling them all into my viewController just doesn't feel right.

I've gone through quite a few iterations already but every time it seems like I need to manually create and individually store all these NSlayoutconstraint properties on the parent Viewcontroller.

What i'm not looking for is a UI extension with a function that sets the constraints and stores them a properties on that class so I can deactivate or change them at will.

```
extension UIView {

func anchorFixedHeight(
        top: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>,
        lead: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>,
        trail: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>,
        height: CGFloat,
        Ypadding: CGFloat,
        Xpadding: CGFloat)
    {
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: Ypadding)
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lead, constant: Xpadding)
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trail, constant: -Xpadding)
    }
```

}

But this wont work because NSlayouconstrain.activate() takes in array of constraints and once you set an achor it turns into an anchor constraint.

I've been trying to store them as properties, but swift wont allow stored properties in extensions. But I also do not want to but I also do not want to duplicate all these constraint properties in all my Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like this

```
class CusView:UIView {

     var top:NSLayoutConstraint!
     var lead:NSLayoutConstraint!
     var tra:NSLayoutConstraint!
     var heigh:NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       top =  self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 12)
       heigh =   self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12)
       lead =  self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 12)
       tra =  self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -12)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([top,lead,tra,heigh])


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed the best solution!